# Can i add an auto complete field in editable table in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am creating a billing software with JavaFX. I already created an autocomplete TextField using [ControlsFX](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx)  library.
But i need to add the same auto completion while editing an editable table just like in the following image.

Is there any way to implement this in JavaFX?

[image: Editable Table Auto Complete]

Comment: sure, why not ;) Just implement a custom tableCell - for pointers read a code for specialized cells that come with core fx and do something similar.

Comment: Yeah. Will see that.. It would be great, if you provide some references. 